# JQuery text box click function that increments value even when text box is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user clicks the mouse in the “Principle” text box, the value increases by $1000. This should work even when the is text box is empty.

The function only works when there is already a value in the text box. The value shows NaN when I click it while it is empty.

```
$("#principal").click(function () {
            var p = parseFloat($("#principal").val());
            p = p + 1000.00;
            $("#principal").val(p); 
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would solve your problem:

```
$("#principal").click(function () {
            var p = parseFloat($("#principal").val() || 0);
            p = p + 1000.00;
            $("#principal").val(p); 
        });
```

Comment: You could also place the `|| 0` outside of `parseFloat`s arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `|| 0` as some kind of "fallback". If the parseFloat function is falsy, it set's 0 as value instead.

I've also changed `p = p + 1000.00` to `p += 1000.000`, but just for design reasons.

```
$("#principal").click(function () {
    var p = parseFloat($("#principal").val()) || 0;
    p += 1000.00;
    $("#principal").val(p);
});
```

Comment: Good answer, but it is always helpful to add even a small bit of explanation as to how your code differs from the question and what problem it addresses.

Comment: This change does not affect the whole functionality, so i would call it a "cosmetic change".

Comment: Sorry, you're right. For some reason I thought OP just had "p = 1000". Carry on :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#principal").click(function () {
        var p = parseFloat($("#principal").val());
if($("#principal").val().length == 0)
{
  p = 1000.00;
}
else
{
  p = p + 1000.00;
}
  $("#principal").val(p); 
});
```

Comment: This won't work since parseFloat will return `NaN` for an empty string and `NaN` doesn't have a length property. (This will give `TypeError: Object NaN has no method 'length'`)